# How do I set default value for a foreign key column in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012, constraints, default

I am adding a new column in an existing table with preloaded data. This column uses a primary key from another table and I want to default this to **5**. I have tried the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE group
ADD group_type INT
GO
ALTER TABLE group
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_group_type DEFAULT 5 FOR group_type
GO
```

I was expecting on alter of the *group* table then all the values will be filled with **5** but instead its NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Naming default constraint with `FK_` prefix is a bad practice.

Comment: what do you prpose i should name it?

Comment: `DF_group_type` for example, since `FK_` prefix is usually used for naming `foreign key` constraints and can mislead

Comment: oh it looks like ive not actually created a FOREIGN KEY constraint.. which is what i wanted to do

Comment: For new comers, you can do this all in a single `ALTER TABLE` command, for more information, [check out my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46573403/398630).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, it set the foreign key constraint, default value, and updated existing table records all in a single `ALTER TABLE` statement.  I'm using a SQL Azure database (via SQL Management Studio), so, YMMV.

```
ALTER TABLE Group
    ADD GroupTypeId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DK_GroupTypeId DEFAULT (5) WITH VALUES
    CONSTRAINT FK_GroupTypeId FOREIGN KEY
    REFERENCES [dbo].[GroupType] (GroupTypeId)

GO
```

It took a while to run, but a subsequent select, showed the rows had the correct default value for those columns.

*Disclaimer: I edited the above query from my table / key names to yours without re-testing it, so you may want to double check it for any typos or other mismatches; The syntax should be the same though.*

Answer (score 2):

First of all, adding a DEFAULT constraint (in it's own SQL statement) to a column does not effect existing data in that column. It only effects new INSERTS to that table which do not provide a value for that column.

Second, you haven't created a FOREIGN KEY constraint here.

EDIT:

Here would be one way to create the FK correctly

```
ALTER TABLE group
ADD group_type_id INT
GO

ALTER TABLE group 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_groupType FOREIGN KEY (group_type_id) 
REFERENCES group_type (group_type_id)
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE group
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_groupType
FOREIGN KEY (group_type_id)
REFERENCES group_type (group_type_id)` is this how you do it?

Comment: Tried that but I got the following error: `Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Foreign key 'fk_groupType ' references invalid column 'group_type_id' in referencing table 'group'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.` am i meant to add the column first?

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any reason why there's two `ALTER TABLE`? Because I tried below and it worked. I also managed to get it so existing data in the column gets changed to 5
`ALTER TABLE group
ADD group_type_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (5) ,
CONSTRAINT fk_group_type FOREIGN KEY (group_type_id) REFERENCES group_type`

Comment: six one, half dozen the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
alter table [group]
    add group_type int constraint df_group_type default (5) with values
```

However, it doesn't seem a good idea to use constant as a default value for a column, which is supposed to be FK column.

It seems, that may be what actually you are trying to do is following:

```
alter table [group] add column group_type int
GO
update [group] set group_type = (select id from group_type where desc ='typeA')
GO
alter table [group] add constraint FK_group_grouptype foreign key (group_type) references group_type (id)
GO
```

Comment: would it be better/work if i do `default(select id from group_type where desc ='typeA')` ?

Comment: It is not allowed to query data from another table as a source of default value.

Answer (score 0):

Adding default constraint will affect existing rows if you add new not nullable column to table.

```
ALTER TABLE group
ADD group_type INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT DK_group_type DEFAULT 5
GO
```